# How can I play TV Shows on anything other than xbox video?

Tags: windows-8.1, video, xbox-video

I recently purchased a series of a TV Show off the Microsoft Store as at the time I didn't have any credit on iTunes. After I downloaded them I tried to play one using Windows Media player, but said it encountered a problem and refused to play it. I tried with VLC Media player and all I get is a very glitched out picture. [image]

I attempted to covert the video into .avi using DIVX but it still returned the same results. Why is this happening?

Comment: The video is protected by DRM.  You are going to have to use a video player compatiable with Microsoft's Xbox Video DRM.

Comment: So the only way I would be able to play it on any other device would be to remove the DRM, even though apparently Microsoft's is impossible to remove.

Comment: You can either find a video player that supports the DRM or remove the DRM from the file.

Comment: Removing microsofts drm has been proven impossible, while supported devices are microsoft only :/

Comment: You asked the reason "it was happening" so I explained it.  But saying you have to remove the DRM without telling you how or saying you have to use a different video player without making a recomendation doesn't seem like an answer worth submitting.